# Marionette js conditionally stop route or delete route at runtime

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm not sure how to keep certain users from certain routes.

Problem is basically this.  Let's say I have 3 user types, A, B and C, and my app has 10 routes.  I want user type A to access, say, routes 1 through 5, user type B to access routes 6 through 10 and user type C to access routes 3 through 7.

Problem is I need my router before I know the user type, otherwise I would just conditionally add the routes per type.  Can I delete routes at runtime when I find out the type?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: You could check for permissions when each route is called.

Comment: I think if someone types a route in the address bar though I never get the chance?  Is that correct?  Think the router just routes without me being able to intervene.  Feels like maybe I have to remove the route completely to be safe?

Comment: You can catch a [`"route"` event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) in Backbone when any route is triggered, then redirect with `Backbone.history.navigate` if needed.

Comment: Also keep in mind that any routing should be done via standard HTML anchor tags, like `<a href="#/bb-route">link</a>` whenever possible, so the usual case is to catch route change with events, or directly in the route callback.

Comment: Hmmm...  Route event fires after the route is complete.  So you're saying route them back afterward.  I'd have to know where they came from.  Or maybe route them on to oops page.  Kind of like a double route.  Let me see if this works.   Wondering if it will cause a glitch in my UI.  I think when I've reached the onRoute function my controller action for the first (not permitted) route is already under way.  Doesn't seem clean.  The action for the bad route is moving forward at the point I do the forced navigate to error or such.  I'm really looking to prevent the nav altogether if bad.

Comment: Also, you mention all routing should be done via standard HTML anchor tags.  I think you mean when a user clicks in my page?  But I can't prevent the user from typing in the location bar.  If they understand what's going on they can type another route frag at the end of the URL.  I can't prevent that.  I think that's the case I'm looking at here.

Comment: What I meant is that overall, you can't prevent navigation. Anyway, it's JS, so the user has access to the code. When inevitably navigating to an unauthorized route, the user should be presented with an "Unauthorized" page or error message.

Comment: Backbone router has a [`execute` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) you can override to prevent navigation on certain condition.

Comment: *"I think if someone types a route in the address bar though I never get the chance? Is that correct?"* well if the user will the the url and your server will serve the page, you should implement server side validation, backbone can't do anything about it. It can only prevent navigation through the client side

Comment: If you have different user roles and you don't have any server side validation you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i think there are two ways to handle this problem. 1) you can add "beforeRoute" event to marionette router or 2) you can check in your controller "show()" if the current user have access rights.

Option 2), could be like this:

```
const Controller = Object.extend({

show (options) {

    //user login params
    if (user) {
       this._showMainView();
    } else {
        // Route back or something
    }
},

_showMainView () {
    this.layout.getRegion('mainRegion').empty().show(new MainView());
}
```

});